# optimize python findall regex in a loop

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.6

I wish to optimize the following code:

```
def regex_cnt(pattern,ldata):
    return( len( re.findall(pattern, ldata) ) )

patternCollection = []
def countfreq():
    for eachpattern in patternlist:
        patCount = regex_cnt(eachpattern,lData)
        nwpattern = re.sub('[^0-9a-zA-Z]+', '_', eachpattern)
        cnwpattern = nwpattern + "=" + str(patCount)
        patternCollection.append(cnwpattern)
    return(patternCollection)
```

The above code works well if i have just a few patterns to scan for. However, if the pattern list is huge, it gets very slow.  I'm wondering if it is at all possible to avoid the `for loop` here?

I'm using python 2.6 (i dont have control of the system this script runs on so I cant upgrade to the latest version of python).

Please advise.

Comment: You are missing some parentheses on function `regex_cnt` and sample definitions for `pattern` and `ldata` (like ones giving you issues).

Comment: Not what you asked about, but you don't have to put `return(value)` because `return` is not a function. You can just have `return value`. Your way doesn't really hurt anything, but it could be confusing for people reading your code.

Comment: I have fixed the parenthesis.